# How do you print the raw queries while running sequelize migrations?

Tags: node.js, database-migration, sequelize.js

I need to print the raw queries that get executed while the migrations are running. Any idea on how this can be done?

I use the --migrate option to run the scripts.

Answer (score -1):

> You can also define a custom function for the logging part. Just pass a function. The first parameter will be the string that is logged.

You can use [logging](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#block-4-line-13), very simple way :), add to migration config loggin: true ([DEPRECATED](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/sequelize.js#L99))

Oh, sorry. I find [source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/bin/sequelize#L223), they don't give chance.

But you can fix this self :) change to "true" for a while.

Or [programmatic use](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/migrations#block-16-line-0):

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  logging: console.log
})

var migrator = sequelize.getMigrator({
  path: process.cwd() + '/database/migrations',
  filesFilter: /\.coffee$/,
  logging: console.log
})

migrator
  .migrate({ method: 'down' })
  .success(function() {
    // The migrations have been executed!
  })
```

Comment: The question is how and what needs to be logged here.